# ::before css not working on mac safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to make sub menu full width on a website using ::before css but its not working on mac safari. Please check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy16d.png) to get an idea of what I am trying to obtain and what it looks like on Mac-Safari.

Below is the CSS code I have used:

```
#header .avia_mega_div .sub-menu::before {
   background:#003b70;
   content: "";
   height: 43px;
   left: 0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 118px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: add you try html code

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a :before for this, try to put a space between your quotes in 'content'

```
content: " ";
```

But for a full width navbar there are better ways to do this but maybe you can share some of your html first.